# 'pip install --user' gives errors

Tags: python, pip, installation, permission-denied

CONTEXT:
I am having trouble installing a module (namely 'plotly').  I have seen a lot of information, which is overwhelming, and so I hope to take the problem step-by-step.

SETUP:

- MacOS High Sierra version 10.13.3
- python version 2.7.10
- possibly relevant: I also installed python 3.6, but when I type `python` version 2.7 gets started (this is another issue that I need to sort out)

WHAT I HAVE TRIED (OR REFRAINED FROM DOING) AND WHAT I UNDERSTAND:

1. Simply typing `pip install plotly` throws an error (and I think I understand why it should): `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython_genutils'`
2. In the past I have used `sudo pip install`, but since then have learned it is a bad thing, so now I am trying to do things "neatly".
3. Disappointingly, doing `pip install --user plotly` also throws an permission error, but not the same as 1.:
   `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/erc/Library/Python/2.7'`
   which I guess is logical since it is trying to install the module in a different location.

At this point I am not sure what to do.

Comment: have you tried `pip3 install plotly` too? this will try to install with python3

Comment: You’ll want to use [venvs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for everything – use `python3` to refer to Python 3.

Comment: I must have seen this before, I can't believe I did not try it... Thanks to Ryan and Marti 157 for the tip!  It will be helpful.

Comment: @nj2237 I didn't know about pip3... but then it means I cannot use with python 2 the module installed with python3, and this is not fully solving my problem.  I am really trying to _understand_ what is going on, before going ahead and "just trying" pip3.  There is probably little chance of messing things up further.

Comment: @Ryan ... and I didn't know about `venv` either!  Thanks for the tip. I might decide to go with python3 from now on, but again this is not telling me why I am getting the error with the install under `--user`

Comment: @Antoine: Assuming “erc” is your username, that indicates you’ve broken your local `Library/Python/2.7` by using sudo. You could try to fix its permissions – `sudo chown -R erc:erc ~/Library/Python`

Comment: On MacOS, the correct command for permission fixup should be `sudo chown -R erc:staff /Users/erc/Library/Python/`. The failure on `pip install --user` is a consequence of using `sudo pip install` previously.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks! Yes indeed I have used "sudo install..." in the past, and now I see the consequences!

Comment: @hoefling Thanks to you too!  Now you and Ryan give me two different solutions, I am not sure how to decide... should I flip a coin?  But thanks again!

Comment: There are no user groups in MacOS, thus Ryan's command should give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pip is not the best idea, try using virtualenv:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

The installation of virtualenv shouldn’t throw an error.
Look up the usage, or use this reference:
http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/virtualenv.html

Also, try python3 to execute 3.6.

Comment: I had also tried this, and guess what, it gave me `'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.pyc'` ...